# Why does the sequence $a_n = \frac{n^P}{e^n}$ converge to 0?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Why does the sequence $a_n = \frac{n^P}{e^n}$ converge to $0$?

I'm having some difficulty understanding how $P$ works in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sequence converges if the function $f(x)=\frac{{{x^P}}}{{{e^x}}}$ converges as $x$ approaches infinity. The P+1'th derivative of the numerator is zero, while the same derivative of the denominator is $e^x$. So by L'Hôpital's rule, the limit of $f(x)$ is zero. This argument works if P is a positive integer. If not, the P'th (rounded up to an integer) derivative is $x$ to a negative power, so again by L'Hôpital's rule the limit is zero.

Do you need an answer more basic than that, one that does not use L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: L'Hopital's rule works... why is the p+1'th derivative zero (the question does state that p>0)?  I'm just trying to understand this conceptually... it seems to me that if P is some arbitrary number then it is possible for this to diverge.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x^2$, so $p=2$. The first derivative is $2x$, the second derivative is 2, and the third derivative is... zero. You can prove this by induction on $p$ for any positive integer. Now consider $f(x)=x^{1.5}$. The first derivative is $1.5x^{0.5}$ and the second is $0.75x^{-0.5}$. Again, the same thing happens for any non-integral positive $p$. You should already know that $x^{-0.5}$ approaches zero as $x$ approaches infinity. The numerator either equaling zero or approaching zero (and the denominator not doing this) means the limit is zero, by L'Hôpital.

Comment: I see.  So in questions like these, p is considered a constant?  I guess that's what I was unsure of.

Comment: Yes, that is the convention.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let $s=\lfloor p\rfloor$ then we have $n^p\le n^{s+1}$ and by the Taylor series we have

$$e^n\ge \frac{n^{s+2}}{(s+2)!}$$
and use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Thanks but I unfortunately have yet to learn Taylor series.

Comment: You can also find the desired result by the L'Hôpital's rule or by using the series...

Answer (score 0):

It holds that $x^n<\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ if x is large enough. With

$x^n<\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}<\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{x^k}{k!}<\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}=e^x$

we can conclude that $e^x$ grows faster than every power of x.

(i.e. for x large enough the term will be smaller than every given $\epsilon >0$)

Answer (score 0):

By the Bernoulli inequality the sequence given by 
$$ a_n = \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n $$
is increasing and converging towards $e^x$, hence:
$$0\leq\frac{x^p}{e^x}<\frac{x^p}{\left(1+\frac{x}{p+1}\right)^{p+1}}<\frac{(p+1)^{p+1}}{x}\xrightarrow[x\to+\infty]{} 0.$$